# VBA error Method 'Add' of object 'SortFields' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to sort a list from column A of excel sheet. I recorded the macro and wrote the subroutine by replacing the activeworksheet by my sheet object. Still I got following error even though the code till this line works fine and to my knowledge there is no problem with the declaration.
Error: Run-time-error '-2147417851(80010105)
'Method 'Add' of object 'SortFields' failed.!

```
Dim ExlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim ExlWS As Excel.Worksheet

Set ExlWB = ExlApp.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sample.xlsx")
Set ExlWS = ExlWB.Sheets(1)

ExlWS.Range("$A$2:$B$" & Rows + 1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
ExlWS.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ExlWS.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ExlWS.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:B" & ExlWS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Can anyone tell what might be the error.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share the complete code. I have a feeling that you have not fully qualified your objects

Comment: its a big code, divided into functions. I'm performing a lot of operations on the data and then bringing it to the excel sheet. There I'm removing the duplicate data and sorting it to ascending order. Before setting the order to ascending, the code works fine. will try to put more lines here for your ref.

Comment: No that is ok. I already posted an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comment above, you have not fully qualified your range objects

You are missing `ExlWS` before `Range("A2")` and `.Range("A2:B"...`

Your code can be written as

```
ExlWS.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ExlWS.Range("A2"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ExlWS.Sort
    .SetRange ExlWS.Range("A2:B" & ExlWS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

BTW post xl2007+, I never used the code the macro recorder gave me for sorting data. I still use the code from Excel 2003

For example

```
With ExlWS.Range("A2:B" & ExlWS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

    .Sort Key1:=ExlWS.Range("A2"), _
                Order1:=xlAscending, _
                Header:=xlGuess, _
                OrderCustom:=1, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
                DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Siddharth... It worked perfectly fine... Thanks again. :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)